# Selenium WebDriver, get from DOM, from empty value

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have field, that after few minutes will be filled. So far so good.
But when is filled, in inspect elements it's look like:

```
<div class="column1 last">
              <input type="text" name="usedFile" size="100" value="" readonly="readonly" style="width:99%" class="disabled">
            </div>
```

So, in front-page, the text is visible: "Some text", but when i click inspect element, it's show this above.
So how, I can get the text from filed? It's DOM this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a textbox so you cannot use getText() in it. To get data out of it , you need following code

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.name("usedFile")).getAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.name("usedFile")).getText();
```

Comment: This works, but after
System.out.printf(text);
Print me, empty row, so, can't get the text.

Comment: is there any text in the input? thats the only thing i can guess is wrong, if text is present then the above snippet will find it.

Comment: In front page - the text present, but in source code of the page - doesn't present. And this is the problem, why is not present and how to catch it?